# .htaccess not working on prodiction server - local works

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my .htaccess
I have build a link shortener like bit.ly.

New requests like www.domain.com/jdJdh should be redirected to the index.php
On my local development server the .htaccess rewrite works fine, but on the production server, i just get an error 500.

this ist my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The apache version is 2.2.22.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: please try to see beyond the error 500, there is apache log that gives you further details about the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you should check your apache configuration, like this:

`AllowOverride All`


    `Order allow,deny`


    `Allow from all`

Hope it helps you.

---

Update:

> When this directive is set to None, then .htaccess files are completely ignored. In this >case, the server will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem.
>
> from: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: I don´t know why, but it works now.
Could you explain this to me?

I have copy the line in my htaccess and load it ion the server.
After that i have tried my programm and get an 500.

Than i have erased the line and load it up, now it works.

Thank you so far, but could you explain me why this solution works?^^

Comment: @derbronko I updated the answer, hope I make it clear.